# Возможно ли получить текст из cmd после Process.Start?

Tags: c#, cmd

Можно ли получить текст из cmd после ...

```
Process _process = new Process ();

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();


startInfo.FileName = "filename";
startInfo.Arguments = "/p /a /c" ;

_process.StartInfo = startInfo;
_process.Start();
```

Попробовал как вы посоветовали но выскакивает ошибка как вы думаете, как можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое интересное, что вызов срабатывает ...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если речь о получении вывода консольной команды, то попробуйте следующий подход:

```
startInfo.FileName = "filename";
startInfo.Arguments = "/p /a /c";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

_process.StartInfo = startInfo;
_process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
_process.Exited += process_Exited;

_process.Start();
```

Остается только написать обработчики `process_OutputDataReceived` и `process_Exited`.

---

Если выхлоп у процесса небольшой и быстрый, то можно просто добавить

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

А потом прочитать весь вывод:

```
string output = _process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Не, не получается,  ошибка вылазит (

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy Раз вы использовали первый подход, то собирать данные нужно в методе `process_OutputDataReceived`, а не в `process_Exited`. И читать тогда нужно не из `_process.StandardOutput`, а из  `e.Data`.

Comment: @Dmity D. поменял, но событие так и не срабатывает :(

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy Попробуйте еще установить `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` перед запуском процесса. Обновил ответ.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ вам спасибо, помогло :)))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

```vb
ChDir("D:\Некий Путь")
Dim Info As New ProcessStartInfo With {.FileName = "cmd.exe", .Arguments = "/k ""smth.bat""", .RedirectStandardOutput = True, .RedirectStandardError = True, .UseShellExecute = False, .CreateNoWindow = True}
Dim Prc As Process = Process.Start(Info)

Do
  Dim Line As String = Await Prc.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()
  If Line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
  RtbStart1.Text += Line + vbCrLf
Loop
```