# Получение строки из Python скрипта в С#

Tags: c#, python, cmd

Нужно запустить Python3 скрипт на С#. IronPython, [как выяснилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830053/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-python-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B5-ironpython-%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9?noredirect=1#comment1326304_830053), поддерживает только python2. В итоге отлично получается запускать скрипт просто передав строку в терминал:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C python J:\\workspace\\Python\\telegram_client\\client.py";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Таким способом строка strCmdText передается в терминал, и скрипт отрабатывает отлично. 
ВОПРОС: Как получить строку(или иные данные) из этого скрипта client.py? Возможно можно дописать что то в сам скрипт что бы была передача значения или что то сможете подсказать другое? Спасибо!=)

Если кому интересно: [Обсуждение по вопросу запуска файла через cmd.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли получить текст из cmd после Process.Start?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484488/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-cmd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-process-start)

Comment: И еще может пригодиться [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804172/Проблемы-с-кодировкой-в-c/804186#804186).

Comment: не обязательно cmd.exe запускать. Можно напрямую python.exe запустить. Перенаправление вывода команды работает также как и для других дочерних процессов. Особенность к python относящаяся: если не достаточно ANSI codepage (типа cp1251), то можно выставить PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 переменную окружения при запуске (и декодировать вывод, используя utf-8 кодировку), чтобы произвольные Unicode символы поддерживать (если python двоичные данные возвращает типа картинки, то вывод как байты, а не текст следует читать—могут быть сложности на Windows: к примеру, powershell может повредить ввод/вывод команды

Comment: ..[продолжение] [Decode powershell output possibly containing non-ascii unicode characters into a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33936074/4279)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за информацию, сейчас буду пробовать, разбираться!

Comment: @jfs Точно спасибо за наводку, я и не подумал о том что можно python.exe запустить сразу. И понял что нужно использовать в С# StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() Для чтения вывода. Но остается вопрос, как должен выглядить этот вывод нужной мне строки в скрипте Python? Неужели как Print(stiring)? Недопонимание только по этому вопросу осталось))

Comment: @jfs в итоге тестов понял что print() и есть вывод в python. Вообщем то это должно было быть очевидно для меня... В итоге все получилось без проблем по вашей ссылке и тому методу StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() Спасибо всем!

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ, чтобы другим людям с похожей проблемой помочь (цель Stack Overflow) — это [явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: в качестве формата обмена данных между командами (если построчный вывод текста недостаточен), можно json или http://jsonlines.org использовать (что больше подходит): `print(json.dumps(data))`

Comment: @jfs да json это следующая ступенька думаю в организации обмена данными. Буду изучать вопрос, Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огромное спасибо ребятам за помощь! В итоге для решения поставленного вопроса был использован следующий код:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C python J:\\workspace\\Python\\telegram_client\\client.py");
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();

        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        while (!p.HasExited)
        {
            q.Append(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
        string r = q.ToString();
```

В python скрипте client.py данные выводятся через print(result). В кодировке проблем не возникало. Но по кодировке(если возникнет проблема) можете почитать [по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804172/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-c/804186#804186)

Comment: Буду признателен если дополните вопрос своими решениями данного вопроса, ибо решение все равно не самое лаконичное)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел очень интересную статью как вызвать метод написанный на Python в C#
[Cсылка на статью](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/)

Используется ***IronPython*** (тестировал NuGet версии 3.4.1)

**Файл calc.py**

```
class Calculator:
   def add(self, argA, argB):
      return argA+argB
   def sub(self, argA, argB):
      return argA-argB
```

**Файл Program.cs (.NET 8.0)**

```
    using IronPython.Hosting; 
   
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    dynamic exfile = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\Григорий\source\repos\TestToR\TestToR\bin\Debug\net8.0\calc.py");
    dynamic calc = exfile.Calculator();

    double a = 7.5;
    double b = 2.5;
    double res;
    res = calc.add(a, b);
```

Как и ожидалось, результат вернулся равный 10.